# Do i load my entity faster using key in objectify?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

i can load using key

```
Employee e = ofy().load().key(Key.create( Employee.class,employeeId)).now();
```

But if i find it using some field

```
Employee e = ofy().load().type(Employee.class).filter("employeeEmail",employeeEmail).first().now();
```

Do i load my entity faster using key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, loading by key is faster and cheaper. You avoid an unnecessary index lookup.

Comment: senks! you realy help me, becase I am facing the some dilemma.

Comment: In addition, if the entity has the `@Cache` annotation and is in memcache... it is *much* faster.